# Laravel Add 30 minutes in field. Example: $is_expired = $created_at + 30minutes;

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I want to add two timestamps, like in this example:

```
$created_at = "2018-07-23 12:15:43";
$is_expired = $created_at + 30mins;
```

The content of `$is_expired` should be `2018-07-23 12:45:43`

Comment: Is this in a model?

Comment: You can use the carbon class in laravel

Comment: @apokryfos yes in model.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-addsub) you can do

```
$is_expired = $created_at->addMinutes(30);
```

Carbon is installed by default in Laravel and your dates should be automatically mutated by Laravel.

If the date is not mutated then you can parse them to Carbon instance using `Carbon::Parse($created_at)`

Or if you have `$dates = []` in your model you should add the `created_at` in it like so

```
protected $dates = [
    'created_at',
    'updated_at',
    'deleted_at'
];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use core php functions:

```
//set timezone
date_default_timezone_set('GMT');

$date = new DateTime();
$created_at = $date->format('U = Y-m-d H:i:s');
$unixTimestamp = time() + 1800; // 30 * 60 

$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimestamp($unixTimestamp);
$is_expired = $date->format('U = Y-m-d H:i:s');
```